# Why are messages sent to trace source missing from all but the first unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I observe a weird behavior with Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 1. When using logging through .NET Framework `TraceSource` inside the unit tests, only the first unit test contains the logging output.

This is the way to reproduce the issue:

An empty unit test project contains the `UnitTest1` class which looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private readonly TraceSource trace = new TraceSource("Demo", SourceLevels.All);

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        this.trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "Test 1 (trace source)");
        Console.WriteLine("Test 1 (console)");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        this.trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "Test 2 (trace source)");
        Console.WriteLine("Test 2 (console)");
    }
}
```

The `App.config` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="Demo" switchValue="Critical, Error, Warning, ActivityTracing, Information, Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="ConsoleTraceListener" />
          <add name="TextFileListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="ConsoleTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
      <add name="TextFileListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="tests.log" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

When running the tests from Visual Studio:

- The output of the first unit test is:

  ```
  Test Name:  TestMethod1
  Test Outcome:   Passed
  Result StandardOutput:  
  Demo Information: 0 : Test 1 (trace source)
  Test 1 (console)
  ```

  Both the messages from trace source and console are shown.
- The output of the second unit test is:

  ```
  Test Name:  TestMethod2
  Test Outcome:   Passed
  Result StandardOutput:  Test 2 (console)
  ```

  While the output from `Console.WriteLine` works well, the one from `TraceSource.TraceEvent` is not shown.

Running the tests from the console by executing `mstest /testcontainer:UnitTestProject1.dll` reproduces the problem as well. The `stdout` reported for the first test contains two lines; the second test's `stdout` has one line only.

Why isn't logging traced for all but the very first test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround consists of wrapping the default `TextWriter` which uses the underlying `Console.Out` text writer to send the logs:

```
public class CustomTextWriter : TextWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get
        {
            return Console.Out.Encoding;
        }
    }

    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        Console.Out.Write(value);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

The writer is then used in a custom trace listener similar to [one used in .NET Framework](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/ConsoleTraceListener.cs,d34b6cbcf7aebc48):

```
public class ConsoleTraceListener : TextWriterTraceListener
{
    public ConsoleTraceListener() : base(new CustomTextWriter())
    {
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
    }
}
```

which is declared in App.config like this:

```
<add name="ConsoleTraceListener"
     type="UnitTestProject1.ConsoleTraceListener, UnitTestProject1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
```

This produces the expected output, **although it is still unclear why the problem exists in the first place**. By checking `Console.Out` and the underlying stream, it doesn't seem that something gets disposed or closed after the first test ends (if it would, why would [the current implementation of `Out`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,301) do nothing, and why would text sent to `Console.WriteLine` appear in logs?)